# Why is Gist showing "File suppressed. Click to show."?

Tags: gist

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/jhorsman/f19159df4ff054c58bcb) is showing a message `File suppressed. Click to show.` on one of the files. Why is this file suppressed?

The file contains a bookmarklet, starting with `javascript:`, perhaps that is not safe?

Comment: @JacobKrall Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. This question is covered in the "software tools commonly used by programmers" bit of the list of on topic questions. Also there is a GIST tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gist with about 156 questions and counting so the general consensus is that questions about Gist are on topic.

Answer (score 0):

I have one that is not dangerous, only a variable declaration, but it is very long. Perhaps that is the reason? (length).

Answer (score 0):

Me too. When I created a bookmarklet I was surprised too for that message, so I googled and came here.

Initially I had a js code in one line and a comment with a word "bookmark", but I tried and pasted the full code and later the one line bookmarlet specifying it. Also to reassure I pasted the bookmarklet in a comment too

Here you can see: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/MangaRed/5d123f602a8a1aa26452)